# Plottability of scalar times vector products

Tags: matlab, vector

I have created two functions: `frame` and `t1`. The first one (for simplicity I have replaced a certain matrix with `eye` here) returns three 3-dimensional vectors.

```
function [frames] = frame(a1,a2,a3)

      L = a1*a2*a3*eye(3);

      frames(1,:)= L*([1,0,0])';
      frames(2,:)=L*([0,1,0])';
      frames(3,:)=L*([0,0,1])';

end
```

The second function takes two scalars (`B`, `phi1`) and three vectors (through the matrix `Frame`) as input and returns another one:

```
function [t1] = t1(B,Frame,phi1) 

 ex=Frame(1,:);
 ey=Frame(2,:);
 ez=Frame(3,:); 

 t1 = -sin(phi1)*ex  - cos(B)*cos(phi1)*ey  + cos(phi1)*sin(B)*ez ;

end
```

When I want to plot or do any operations with `phi1` or `B` being vectors, clearly I encounter problems, because terms like `sin(phi1)*ex`end up having the wrong dimensions. Replacing them with `sin(phi1).*ex` is also clearly wrong, as `ex` will always have dimension 3, whereas `sin(phi1)` will have the dimension of `phi1`.

Example:

```
phi1=linspace(0,2*pi);
plot(phi1,t1(pi/2,frame(1,1,1),phi1))
```

.

```
Error using  * 
Incorrect dimensions for matrix multiplication. Check that the number of columns in the first matrix matches the
number of rows in the second matrix. To perform elementwise multiplication, use '.*'.
```

What is a workaround this problem, that I have encountered in many other instances?

Comment: What version of MATLAB are you using? This may be relevant for any answers involving implicit expansion

Comment: @Wolfie vers. R2018a

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You just need to transpose `phi1`, the rest of the dimensions are fine.

```
plot(phi1, t1(pi/2,frame(1,1,1),phi1.'));
```

[image: output]